# jQuery with html / php form (using ajaxForm) working only once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to solve this for a while now and no success. Stackoverflow needed!

Basically, what the script does is fetch user profile pictures from the database.
A moderator can see them and click on the "Ban" button, and then the banPeopleProcess.php file has the code to remove the picture from the database etc.
Example: http://screencast.com/t/uFtFgKxYx4s

Each picture is a form, they all have the same form id. Here's the HTML (in php echo):

```
<div>
<form id=\"banPeopleForm\" action=\"banPeopleProcess.php\" method=\"post\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"toid\" value=". $i ." />
    <input id=\"banPeopleBtn\" type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"BAN\" />
</form>
</div>
```

The JS currently looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function banPeople() {
    $('#banPeopleForm').ajaxForm(function() {
        $('#banPeopleBtn').hide(); 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#banPeopleBtn').click(function() {
        banPeople();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

- Only the first loaded picture actually does what it should be doing (button is hiding, form submitted etc.)
- For the following pictures, the JS doesn't work, they just follow the normal HTML form - when clicking the ban button, we are redirected to banPeopleProcess.php.
- With that said it seems like only the first photo id gets loaded with the JS, and the others not. I still don't know what to try.

Help greatly appreciated guys!!

Comment: the same id is going to confuse things! Plus, once in the function use $(this) in the function instead of the id

Comment: Do you mean each picture should have a different id?

Comment: every item on the page should have a different id, IDs are meant to be unique. You could use something like #banPeopleBtn_[NO] ... i.e. #banPeopleBtn_1, #banPeopleBtn_2

Comment: I use a for loop to fetch all the pictures from the database. I could assign each picture a different ID within php, but then how would I pass that unique id to the js for each pic ?

Comment: how are you generating the list of images?

Comment: I have a for loop that goes through each picture in the database, and echo's it (the html code in my post is the php echo part).

Comment: Use the key of the loop as the id. Use foreach, instead of for. In the php when you generate the array from the DB make sure you use the id as the key. i.e. $data[$id] = [data from db]

Comment: All good. But then how do I make the js code call the right form ID?

Comment: Use $('[id|='banPeopleBtn']').click(...); Use $(this) in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different id for each picture. 
use different form id and submit id for each picture.
Make dynamic the javascript id as well as followed $('#banPeopleBtn'+id).hide(); As javascript can not work with same id in same page.

Comment: I don't really get the "+id". How will it fetch the right id from the picture forms?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
function banPeople(id){
 alert(id);
}
</script> 

 <input id="banPeopleBtn" onclick="banPeople('<?php echo id;?>')" type="submit" name="submit" value="BAN" />

Comment: Simple & powerful... very nice, thanks a bunch, I love that onclick a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent `form` from submitting php file and use ajax for calling your php.something like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#banPeopleBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        banPeople();    
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "banPeopleProcess.php"
        });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried the code, and basically when I click ban for the first image, the button doesn't hide hidden / the form doesn't get called. However the ban button for the other images work, altough not with JS (it just redirects to the php process page). Most likely again due the the ID, I need to find a way to make them each unique and call them from js I think.

Comment: it seems you should simply use `$('#banPeopleBtn').hide();` instead of calling `banPeople();` try it.